# PHP: Read file into array

Tags: php, regex

I have a large (~5MB) text file with a content similar to this:

```
> -L"FIR ANTANANARIVO"
55.5000001034   -19.0053549236
55.5000001034   -10.0053549152
55.5000001034   -19.0053549236
> -L"FIR ANTOFAGASTA"
-69.76998889    -17.96612222
-69.95860556    -18.24945
-80.2033334761  -18.35000067
> -L"FIR ASHGABAT"
61.3850333  38.655
60.2866333  39.8950333
56.4517 40.055
```

Data is shorted to three lines each for readability. Each data set can be longer than ~200 lines.

Using `\> -L\".*\"` as matching string only returns the whole line and not the part in quotes only.

Desired output array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIR ANTANANARIVO
            [1] => 55.5000001034    -19.0053549236
            [2] => 55.5000001034    -10.0053549152
            [3] => 55.5000001034    -19.0053549236
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIR ANTOFAGASTA
            [1] => -69.76998889 -17.96612222
            [2] => -69.95860556 -18.24945
            [3] => -80.2033334761   -18.35000067
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIR ASHGABAT
            [1] => 61.3850333   38.655
            [2] => 60.2866333   39.8950333
            [3] => 56.4517  40.055
        )
)
```

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$firs = file_get_contents('data/firs.txt');
preg_match_all("/^\> -L\".*\"?(?=\n\>|\z)", $firs, $treffer);
print_r($treffer);
```

Comment: You need to show your loading/parsing code. We are not just going to bang something out for you.

Comment: Since you mention what happens with that regex, it follows that you already have code for this. So are you leaving the whole solution as an exercise to the answerer for our own benefit?

Comment: This looks like one of those situations where `file()` comes in handy.

Comment: Gentlemen, better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> returns the whole line and **not the part in quotes only**.

You might forget to group it. Get it from matched group from index 1.

```
\> -L\"(.*)\"
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yD4tX3/1)

---

Try with *Positive Lookbehind* and *Positive Lookahead*. In that case there is no need to catch it from groups.

```
(?<=\> -L\").*(?=\")
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yD4tX3/2)

---

Get all the the desired values in matched groups from index 1.

```
 ((?<=\> -L\").*(?=\")|^-?\d.*$)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/yD4tX3/4)

Comment: Dear @Braj thank you for your effort - I tip my hat for even making examples available! Impressive! The last one matches just perfect. However I'm now struggling putting the matches into an array in the above mentioned format. May I ask for your assistance once more?